# What could possibly go wrong with this HTTP caching scheme?

Tags: c#, .net, http, caching

I know that rolling your own HTTP caching is probably ill-advised, but this is what is being used on a project. It appears to have cached a response that is odd, see below, as this request was for an image. It appears to have been a non-error response (otherwise it would not have been cached), however it was not the image, it was an HTML page.. What response codes could be interpreted as success by unity, other than 200?

```
IEnumerator ReallyDownloadFile(string url, string filename, System.Action<string> on_complete,System.Action<string> on_error, bool allow_caching)
{
    WWW www = new WWW (url);

    yield return www;

    if ((www.error != "")&&(www.error != null)) {
        on_error.Invoke (www.error);
    } else {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes (Application.persistentDataPath + "/filecache/" + filename, www.bytes);
        on_complete.Invoke (Application.persistentDataPath + "/filecache/" + filename);
    }
}
```

This is the response. I have no idea where this came from. Router? CDN possibly. Can you explain what happened?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
<meta name="csrf_token" content="2qe6UtbjdrA6e4ol/eNeo5988K4uoH7r"/>
<meta name="csrf_token" content="UHQ2/wbKRgNdaE14EMIHbKUsa2bLJurm"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv='Pragma' content='no-cache'/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            /*
             JQuery is not compatible with PSP & NDSi
             script execution will stop when the jquery import.
             we should put the following script before the jquery is imported
             */
            var hardwarePlatform = navigator.platform.toLowerCase();
            var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
            var isPsp = (agent.indexOf("playstation") != -1);
            var isNdsi = (agent.indexOf("nintendo dsi") != -1);
            if (isPsp || isNdsi) {
                window.location.href = "notsupported.html";
            }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/log4javascript_lite.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/redirect.js"></script>

        <title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var DEFAULT_GATEWAY_IP = "192.168.1.1";
            var DEFAULT_GATEWAY_DOMAIN = new Array();
            var GATEWAY_DOMAIN = new Array();
            var AJAX_HEADER = '../';
            var AJAX_TAIL = '';
            var AJAX_TIMEOUT = 30000;

            var MACRO_NO_SIM_CARD = '255';
            var MACRO_CPIN_FAIL = '256';
            var MACRO_PIN_READY = '257';
            var MACRO_PIN_DISABLE = '258';
            var MACRO_PIN_VALIDATE = '259';
            var MACRO_PIN_REQUIRED = '260';
            var MACRO_PUK_REQUIRED = '261';

            var log = log4javascript.getNullLogger();            
            var hardwarePlatform = navigator.platform.toLowerCase();
            var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

            var isIpod = hardwarePlatform.indexOf("ipod") != -1;
            var isIphone = hardwarePlatform.indexOf("iphone") != -1;
            var isIpad =  hardwarePlatform.indexOf("ipad") != -1;
            var isAndroid = agent.indexOf("android") !=-1;

            log.debug("INDEX : hardwarePlatform = " + hardwarePlatform);
            log.debug("INDEX : agent = " + agent);
            function gotoPageWithoutHistory(url) {
                log.debug('MAIN : gotoPageWithoutHistory(' + url + ')');
                window.location.replace(url);
            }

            // internal use only
            function _recursiveXml2Object($xml) {
                if ($xml.children().size() > 0) {
                    var _obj = {};
                    $xml.children().each(function() {
                        var _childObj = ($(this).children().size() > 0) ? _recursiveXml2Object($(this)) : $(this).text();
                        if ($(this).siblings().size() > 0 && $(this).siblings().get(0).tagName == this.tagName) {
                            if (_obj[this.tagName] == null) {
                                _obj[this.tagName] = [];
                            }
                            _obj[this.tagName].push(_childObj);
                        }
                        else {
                            _obj[this.tagName] = _childObj;
                        }
                    });
                    return _obj;
                }
                else {
                    return $xml.text();
                }
            }

            // convert XML string to an Object.
            // $xml, which is an jQuery xml object.
            function xml2object($xml) {
                var obj = new Object();
                if ($xml.find('response').size() > 0) {
                    var _response = _recursiveXml2Object($xml.find('response'));
                    obj.type = 'response';
                    obj.response = _response;
                }
                else if ($xml.find('error').size() > 0) {
                    var _code = $xml.find('code').text();
                    var _message = $xml.find('message').text();
                    log.warn('MAIN : error code = ' + _code);
                    log.warn('MAIN : error msg = ' + _message);
                    obj.type = 'error';
                    obj.error = {
                        code: _code,
                        message: _message
                    };
                }
                else if ($xml.find('config').size() > 0) {
                    var _config = _recursiveXml2Object($xml.find('config'));
                    obj.type = 'config';
                    obj.config = _config;
                }
                else {
                    obj.type = 'unknown';
                }
                return obj;
            }

            function getAjaxData(urlstr, callback_func, options) {
                var myurl = AJAX_HEADER + urlstr + AJAX_TAIL;
                var isAsync = true;
                var nTimeout = AJAX_TIMEOUT;
                var errorCallback = null;

                if (options) {
                    if (options.sync) {
                        isAsync = (options.sync == true) ? false : true;
                    }
                    if (options.timeout) {
                        nTimeout = parseInt(options.timeout, 10);
                        if (isNaN(nTimeout)) {
                            nTimeout = AJAX_TIMEOUT;
                        }

                    }
                    errorCallback = options.errorCB;
                }
                var headers = {};
                headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = g_requestVerificationToken;

                $.ajax({
                    async: isAsync,
                    headers: headers,
                    //cache: false,
                    type: 'GET',
                    timeout: nTimeout,
                    url: myurl,
                    //dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                        try {
                            if (jQuery.isFunction(errorCallback)) {
                                errorCallback(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus);
                            }
                            log.error('MAIN : getAjaxData(' + myurl + ') error.');
                            log.error('MAIN : XMLHttpRequest.readyState = ' + XMLHttpRequest.readyState);
                            log.error('MAIN : XMLHttpRequest.status = ' + XMLHttpRequest.status);
                            log.error('MAIN : textStatus ' + textStatus);
                        }
                        catch (exception) {
                            log.error(exception);
                        }
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        log.debug('MAIN : getAjaxData(' + myurl + ') sucess.');
                        log.trace(data);
                        var xml;
                        if (typeof data == 'string' || typeof data == 'number') {
                            if (-1 != this.url.indexOf('/api/sdcard/sdcard')) {
                                data = sdResolveCannotParseChar(data);
                            }
                            if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
                                var parser = new DOMParser();
                                xml = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/xml');
                            }
                            else {
                                //IE
                                xml = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
                                xml.async = false;
                                xml.loadXML(data);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            xml = data;
                        }
                        if (typeof callback_func == 'function') {
                            callback_func($(xml));
                        }
                        else {
                            log.error('callback_func is undefined or not a function');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            function getConfigData(urlstr, callback_func, options) {
                var myurl = '../' + urlstr + '';
                //var myurl = urlstr + "";
                var isAsync = true;
                var nTimeout = AJAX_TIMEOUT;
                var errorCallback = null;

                if (options) {
                    if (options.sync) {
                        isAsync = (options.sync == true) ? false : true;
                    }
                    if (options.timeout) {
                        nTimeout = parseInt(options.timeout, 10);
                        if (isNaN(nTimeout)) {
                            nTimeout = AJAX_TIMEOUT;
                        }
                    }
                    errorCallback = options.errorCB;
                }

                $.ajax({
                    async: isAsync,
                    //cache: false,
                    type: 'GET',
                    timeout: nTimeout,
                    url: myurl,
                    //dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        try {
                            log.debug('MAIN : getConfigData(' + myurl + ') error.');
                            log.error('MAIN : XMLHttpRequest.readyState = ' + XMLHttpRequest.readyState);
                            log.error('MAIN : XMLHttpRequest.status = ' + XMLHttpRequest.status);
                            log.error('MAIN : textStatus ' + textStatus);
                            if (jQuery.isFunction(errorCallback)) {
                                errorCallback(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (exception) {
                            log.error(exception);
                        }
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        log.debug('MAIN : getConfigData(' + myurl + ') success.');
                        log.trace(data);
                        var xml;
                        if (typeof data == 'string' || typeof data == 'number') {
                            if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
                                var parser = new DOMParser();
                                xml = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/xml');
                            }
                            else {
                                //IE
                                xml = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
                                xml.async = false;
                                xml.loadXML(data);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            xml = data;
                        }
                        if (typeof callback_func == 'function') {
                            callback_func($(xml));
                        }
                        else {
                            log.error('callback_func is undefined or not a function');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            function getDomain(){
                getConfigData("config/lan/config.xml", function($xml){
                    var ret = xml2object($xml);
                    if(ret.type == "config")
                    {
                        DEFAULT_GATEWAY_DOMAIN.push(ret.config.landns.hgwurl.toLowerCase());
                        if( typeof(ret.config.landns.mcdomain) != 'undefined' )
                        {
                            GATEWAY_DOMAIN.push(ret.config.landns.mcdomain.toLowerCase());
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                   sync: true
                });
            }

            function getQueryStringByName(item) {
                var svalue = location.search.match(new RegExp('[\?\&]' + item + '=([^\&]*)(\&?)', 'i'));
                return svalue ? svalue[1] : svalue;
            }

            function isHandheldBrowser() {
                var bRet = false;
                if(0 == login_status){
                    return bRet;
                }               
                if (isIphone || isIpod) {
                    log.debug("INDEX : current browser is iphone or ipod.");
                    bRet = true;
                }
                else if (isPsp) {
                    log.debug("INDEX : current browser is psp.");
                    bRet = true;
                }
                else if (isIpad) {
                    log.debug("INDEX : current browser is ipad.");
                    bRet = true;
                }
                else if (isAndroid) {
                    log.debug("INDEX : current browser is android.");
                    bRet = true;
                }
                else {
                    log.debug("INDEX : screen.height = " + screen.height);
                    log.debug("INDEX : screen.width = " + screen.width);
                    if (screen.height <= 320 || screen.width <= 320) {
                        bRet = true;
                        log.debug("INDEX : current browser screen size is small.");
                    }
                }
                log.debug("INDEX : isHandheldBrowser = " + bRet);
                return bRet;
            }

            function update_openNewWindow () {
                if (window.location.href.indexOf('?updataredirect=') > -1) {
                    var tmpUrl = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf("?updataredirect="));
                    var newUrl = "http://" + tmpUrl.substring(tmpUrl.indexOf("?updataredirect=") + 16) + '/';

                    document.getElementById("update_newPage").setAttribute("href", newUrl);
                    document.getElementById("update_newPage").setAttribute("target", "_blank");
                    if($.browser.msie) {
                        $("#update_newPage").get(0).click();
                    } else {
                        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");  
                        evt.initEvent("click", true, true);  
                        document.getElementById('update_newPage').dispatchEvent(evt);
                    }
                 }
            }

            var g_requestVerificationToken = '';
            function getAjaxToken() {
                 getAjaxData('api/webserver/token', function($xml) {
                    var ret = xml2object($xml);
                     if ('response' == ret.type) {
                         g_requestVerificationToken = ret.response.token;

                     }
                }, {
                       sync: true
                });
            }

            getAjaxToken();

        var WangatewayAddr="";
            var gatewayAddr = "";
            var conntection_status = null;
            var service_status = null;
            var login_status = null;
            // get current settings gateway address
            getAjaxData("api/dhcp/settings", function($xml) {
                var ret = xml2object($xml);
                if ("response" == ret.type) {
                    gatewayAddr = ret.response.DhcpIPAddress;
                }
            }, {
                sync : true
            }
            );

            // get connection status
            getAjaxData("api/monitoring/status", function($xml) {
                var ret = xml2object($xml);
                if ("response" == ret.type) {
                    conntection_status = parseInt(ret.response.ConnectionStatus,10);
                    service_status = parseInt(ret.response.ServiceStatus,10);
            WangatewayAddr = ret.response.WanIPAddress;
                }
            }, {
                sync : true
            }
            );
                        // get connection status
            getAjaxData('config/global/config.xml', function($xml) {
            var config_ret = xml2object($xml);  
            login_status = config_ret.config.login;

            }, {
                sync : true
            }
            );
            if ("" == gatewayAddr) {
                gatewayAddr = DEFAULT_GATEWAY_IP;
            }

            var href = "http://" + DEFAULT_GATEWAY_IP;
            try {
                href = window.location.href;
            }
            catch(exception) {
                href = "http://" + DEFAULT_GATEWAY_IP;
            }
            // get incoming url from querystring
            var incoming_url = href.substring(href.indexOf("?url=") + 5);
            // truncate http://
            if (incoming_url.indexOf("//") > -1) {
                incoming_url = incoming_url.substring(incoming_url.indexOf("//") + 2);
            }
            //get *.html
            var incoming_html = "";
            if (incoming_url.indexOf(".html") > -1) {
                incoming_html = incoming_url.substring(incoming_url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, incoming_url.length);
            }
            // truncate tail
            if (incoming_url.indexOf("/") !=  -1) {
                incoming_url = incoming_url.substring(0, incoming_url.indexOf("/"));
            }

            incoming_url = incoming_url.toLowerCase();
            var bIsSmallPage = isHandheldBrowser();
            // var prefix = "http://" + gatewayAddr;
            var g_indexIncomingUrlIsGateway = false;
            // if incoming url == 192.168.1.1 or MobileWifi.home then goto login
            // page
            window.name = getQueryStringByName("version");
            //check login status
            var LOGIN_STATES_SUCCEED = "0";
            var userLoginState = LOGIN_STATES_SUCCEED;
            getAjaxData('api/user/state-login', function($xml) {
                var ret = xml2object($xml);
                if (ret.type == 'response') {
                    userLoginState=ret.response.State;
                }
            }, {
                sync: true
            });

            $(document).ready(function() {

                update_openNewWindow();

                if(true == bIsSmallPage) {
                    if (userLoginState != LOGIN_STATES_SUCCEED) {
                        getAjaxData('config/global/config.xml', function($xml) {
                            var config_ret = xml2object($xml);
                            if(config_ret.type == 'config') {
                                if(config_ret.config.commend_enable == '1') {
                                    gotoPageWithoutHistory("../html/commend.html");
                                    g_indexIncomingUrlIsGateway = true;
                                }else {                                 
                                    g_indexIncomingUrlIsGateway = redirectOnCondition("",'index');
                                }
                            }
                        },{
                            sync: true
                        });

                    } else {                    
                        g_indexIncomingUrlIsGateway = redirectOnCondition("",'index');                   
                    }
                } else {
                    g_indexIncomingUrlIsGateway = redirectOnCondition("",'index');
                }

                $( function() {
                    getDomain();
                    if (g_indexIncomingUrlIsGateway) {
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (conntection_status == 901 && service_status == 2) {
                        if ((incoming_url.indexOf(gatewayAddr)==0)
                || (incoming_url.indexOf(DEFAULT_GATEWAY_DOMAIN)==0)
                || (incoming_url.indexOf(WangatewayAddr)==0)
                || (incoming_url.indexOf(GATEWAY_DOMAIN)==0)){
                               gotoPageWithoutHistory("home.html");
                         }
                         else {
                              gotoPageWithoutHistory("update.html");
                         }
                    }
                    else {
                        gotoPageWithoutHistory("home.html");
                    }
                });

             });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
        <div>
            <a id="update_newPage" href="#" target="_blank"></a>
        </div>
        <noscript>
            Sorry, your browser does not support javascript.
        </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a DNS intercept/attempted redirect by a router. It looks like a situation where a 200 is returned with content that is not what was requested. The question now becomes "How can this type of situation be detected?"

One approach would be to use http://clients1.google.com/generate_204 to tell whether you are behind a captive portal or not: since a 204 would be unlikely to be used by the router in this situation. However this seems like a flawed approach for this use case.

Perhaps this question would be a good example of why one should not roll one's own cache?

Anyway is this necessary at all? I'm starting to think HTTP caching in Unity may just work without this...